# How to delete all items from databese and base adapter

Tags: android, android-database

I have a database to saving all data. There are 3 different activities. First activity has only one word. Second activity has many words and All data go to my database. Third activity All data are being compiled. But I have a problem. I cannot delete all data. There is a little button in 3rd activity. But when I use, My application does nothing. All data are still in my database. I want to delete all data. How can I fix?

My database query:

```
 public void deleteAllName(int id, String name ) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + COL1 + " = '" + id + "' AND "
            + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
    Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: query: " + query);
    Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: Deleting " + name + " from database.");
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

How to get all data :

```
     Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();

    while(data.moveToNext()){

        listDataId.add(data.getString(0)); //all ıds
        analiste.add(data.getString(1));  // all datas


    }
```

My little button :

```
 sil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

              for (int i = 0 ; i< listDataId.size()  ; i++ ) {

              int all_id = Integer.parseInt(listDataId.get(i));
                String all_names = analiste.get(i);

               mDatabaseHelper.deleteAllName(all_id , all_names);
            }
            isleme.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });

}
```

Comment: why you are deleting one by one

Comment: My purpose is generate too many items from these worlds.There is different logic in this project.So I have to erase all datas at first time.

Comment: @BerkayIşıkoğlu I have edited answer. This method will clear all your data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi As per my understanding You can Delete from this code

```
 public void deleteBackGroundTable() {
    String deleteQuery = "DELETE  FROM " + YOUR_TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(deleteQuery);
    Log.e("Offline Table", "deleteBackGroundTable: DELETED !! ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helping.

Comment: @BerkayIşıkoğlu Welcome ... Great to hear, I could help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Very first time you can use in your SqliteDatabaseHelper

```
db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_NAME);
```